# Post json data to API using axios react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to post JSON data to the API using Axios post. but I want to post with body so the can get required fields for them.
my axios Post code:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post(' http://ec2-13-213-17-111.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/home', {
  
    })
     .then((res) => {
    // Res.data is the response from your server
    localStorage.setItem("apiData1", JSON.stringify(res.data));
     
    });
    
   var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("apiData1"));
    console.log(data)
  }
```

I want to store the json response as well please guide me how to do that